# How do I attach a div to the right or left side of another div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simulated chat box, which requires chats to pop up on the left and the right side of the div. Each of these chats are divs as well. I cannot figure out how to append a div to the right side of the outer div. In my code I've appended some text to the div I want to then append to the outer div. I want to do this with vanilla Javascript, if possible.

```
function pressEnter() {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault;
        // get text
        var text = document.getElementById("client_text_area").value;
        // create new div
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.id = "human_chat"
        // create text node to append
        text = document.createTextNode(text);
        newdiv.appendChild(text);
}
```

Comment: I think you are interesting in `left: 100%` or `right: 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `left: 0%` positions a child element within its parent, hugging its left side. Using `left: 50%` positions this child's left side in the very middle of its parent. And so we can see that `left: 100%` will position the child's left against the rightmost edge of its parent. Similarly, `right: 100%` can be used to position children to the *left* of their parent:

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  margin-left: -50px; margin-top: -50px;
  background-color: #900;
}
.parent > .child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: #090;
}

/* These are the rules that should interest you! */
.parent > .child.left { right: 100%; }
.parent > .child.right { left: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child left"></div>
  <div class="child right"></div>
</div>
```

In order to set these values through javascript, you can the modify values on `yourElem.style`.

For example, if you wish for `newdiv` to stick to the right of its parent you can do:

```
newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
newdiv.style.left = '100%';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a Javascript solution as I have to create these divs dynamically.

Comment: Your question is a matter of css positioning. Once you understand the css technique you require, it's quite trivial to translate it into javascript: `newdiv.style.left = '100%';`

Comment: Thank you for the Javascript explanation!

Comment: No problem! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd put this in a comment below Gershom's answer but since I can't comment yet, I'm putting it in an answer.

As Gershom shared, use CSS to style your divs. You can add classes to your div when creating them with JavaScript like the following:

```js
newdiv.classList.add('class-name');
```